# 'using' on mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql

im working on a login server in c# with mysql and i've a question:
I've seen on the internet that the correct way to use MySqlConnection and doing queries is using the "using" statment like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CNN_STRING))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("COMMAND", con))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Well, if i use this the connection will be closed and opened every time, right? The problem is that opening the connection takes about 200ms, will it take this time every time that i try to do a query?

Comment: You normally just open it once, then do all your queries. No need to open it multiple times.

Comment: "using" is the correct way to handle objects that implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bwa4xa9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: See [Connection Pooling in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html)

Comment: @Bxx No - connections are pooled in .NET, so creating one isn't an expensive process.  Keeping a connection open for long periods can cause issues, though.

Answer (score 4):

> Well, if i use this the connection will be closed and opened every time, right?

It will be *closed* automatically.  You still have to *open* it before you use it.

> The problem is that opening the connection takes about 200ms, will it take this time every time that i try to do a query?

You'll have to try it and measure it to know for sure, but connections are pooled in .NET, so creating one isn't an expensive process.  Whether *opening* one will take the same amount of time each time cannot be determined without trying it, since it depends on the quality of your network.

Try it the recommended way, and if it becomes a *measurable* problem for your app overall *then* look for other solutions.

Do NOT go to the other end of the spectrum where you keep a connection open for the life of your app.  If you do, then you constantly have to check to make sure the connection is still open (since it can be closed by other means) and can cause other issues.

Comment: upvote. Last paragraph - ditto. I'm fed up with our code -  all the `Open` and `Close`ings, especially when using `using`.

Comment: not to mention... [orphaned connections](https://coding.abel.nu/2011/12/idisposable-and-using-in-c/).

Answer (score 0):

Nope! Just make sure the logic you're using is within that using block. It will be connected to and disposed of correctly.

Comment: this is not an answer also `using` takes care of auto-disposing

Answer (score 0):

This should open your connection and dispose it properly at the end of the `using` block.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CNN_STRING))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("COMMAND, con);
    //do something
}
```